# What is the nature of this algorithm and How to find its complexity ?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

This algorithm computes the number of ways one can make change for n cents assuming one can use six types of coins. Singles, half dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels and pennies. In the following algorithm, what is this type of algorithm called ? Is it dynamic or greedy ? Also, how do I start about finding the complexity of such an algorithm ?

```
B(n)
count ← 0
s ← 0
while s ≤ n/100
   do srem ← n − 100*s
   s ← s + 1
   h ← 0
   while h ≤ srem/50
       do hrem ← srem − 50*h
       h ← h + 1
       q ← 0
       while q ≤ hrem/25
          do qrem ← hrem − 25*q
          q ← q + 1
          d ← 0
          while d ≤ qrem/10
             do drem ← qrem − 10*d
             d ← d + 1
             ni ← 0
             while ni ≤ drem/5
                 do ni ← ni + 1
                 count ← count + 1
return count
```

I have so far calculated: 
Time complexity `T(n) = 1 + a(1+b(1+c(1+d(1+e*1))))`
a, b, c, d, e are the while loops.

In the worst case, s is n/100, so substituting that on a, and srem <- n - 100*n/100 = 0,

```
T(n) = n/100(1 + 0) = Big-O(n).
```

But when s = 0,

```
T(n) = 1 + 0(1+ ....)
     = Big-O(1)
```

How do I find the time complexity ? Which is the way to go? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is known as *exhaustive search*. You can do much better using dynamic programming.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus If I needed to calculate its complexity, how do I even begin?

Comment: The complexity in this case is roughly (i.e., up to big O) the number of solutions. So you'll have to estimate that.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus by the number of solutions, you mean the number of ways one can make change?

Comment: Right, exactly.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus How do I estimate that systematically , using rules of time complexity analysis?

Comment: You'll have to figure this out yourself. It has nothing to do with time complexity.

Comment: See [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis) for how to go about analysing algorithms in a structured way. That will help you arrive at Yuval's statement.